# How do I show that the Turàn density exists?

Tags: graph-theory

I have the *extremal/Turàn function* defined as
$$
\operatorname{ex}(n, F) = \max\left\{e(G): |G| = n, F \not\subseteq G\right\}
$$
and the *Turàn density*
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\operatorname{ex}(n, F)}{\binom{n}{2}}
$$
I want to show that this limit exists. It’s described as “easy” in my notes, so I feel like I must be missing something obvious.

I can see that $\operatorname{ex}(n, F)/\binom{n}{2}$ is bounded in $[0,1]$, and I think that the idea is to show that this is decreasing in $n$ (so it forms a decreasing bounded sequence, which converges), but I haven’t been able to do this.

I’ve been able to get this far:
$$
\frac{\operatorname{ex}(n+1,F)}{\binom{n+1}{2}}
= \frac{\operatorname{ex}(n+1,F)}{\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}}
= \frac{\operatorname{ex}(n+1,F)}{\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}} \cdot \frac{n-1}{n+1}
\leq \frac{\operatorname{ex}(n+1,F)}{\binom{n}{2}}
$$
but I don’t know how to show that $\operatorname{ex}(n+1,F) \leq \operatorname{ex}(n,F)$, mostly because I’m fairly sure it isn’t true.

How do I finish this proof? Do I need to continue this argument, or is this the wrong line of reasoning entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sequence $ex(n, F)/\binom{n}{2}$ is indeed non-increasing.

To see this, assume w.l.o.g. that $F$ has at least one edge and let $n \geq 3$ be arbitrary. Consider a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, $ex(n, F)$ edges and such that $F \not\subseteq G$. Such a graph always exists, as $F$ has at least one edge.

Now any subset of $n-1$ vertices of $G$ is also $F$-free, and hence spans at most $ex(n-1, F)$ edges. Summing over all subsets of $G$ of size $n-1$ gives a total of at most $n\cdot ex(n-1, F)$ edges. But each edge of $G$ was counted exactly $n-2$ times, so
\begin{equation*}
ex(n, F) \leq \frac{n}{n-2} ex(n-1, F).
\end{equation*}
Dividing by $\binom{n}{2}$ gives
\begin{equation*}
\frac{ex(n, F)}{\binom{n}{2}} \leq \frac{ex(n-1, F)}{\binom{n-1}{2}},
\end{equation*}
as desired.